# System.currentTimeMillis() is differences by severall hours between two devices

Tags: android

When writing an app I realized that the epochtime retrieved by `System.currentTimeMillis()` on two devices, differs by almost 7 hours.
For example one retrieved: 1465999565478, the other 1465976266000.
Is this to be expected? If so will this difference be constant, which would allow for establishing an offset, or can it change somehow?

Comment: What is the time and tmezone on both devices. are they same?

Comment: And you are sure that both of your devices are running with the same current system time? cause [currentTimeMillis()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()) calculates the value between **January 1, 1970 00:00:00.0** and your current system time

Comment: @PankajKumar **time** is important, but **timezone** doesn't matter - [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()) - *This method always returns UTC times, regardless of the system's time zone.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`System.currentTimeMillis()` reports the value of the real-time clock in the device. That could be:

- set by a signal from a mobile carrier (e.g., NITZ)
- set by the device querying an SNTP server
- set by the user via the Settings app

The latter option means that `System.currentTimeMillis()` can report any possible value, within the range of dates and times that the Settings app allows. On rooted devices, users would have even more options for setting the date and time, beyond what Settings supports.

It is safe for you to assume that the time reported by the device is fine for that device and for that user. After all, if the user decided to claim that the current time is 10:21 on 15 June 1977, that is the user's decision to make.

It is not safe for you to assume that the time reported by the device will be related to any time reported by any other device. Either rely on your server for determining times or obtain the current time from other sources (e.g., call an SNTP server yourself).

Note that this is not significantly different than how times work on most other pieces of computer hardware.